# Problema con variable $_GET en ajax

Tags: php

Yo recibo mediante ajax, la variable $imagenTemporal, luego la meto en una variable llamada $datos, donde lo envio a otra funcion, la cuestion es que dentro de ninguna de las dos funciones me reconoce una variable que esta en la url, la he tratado de meter en ambas y nada, lo curioso es que si quito el parametro $datos de la función mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos) si me reconoce la variable

```
class AjaxOC{

public $imagenTemporal;
public function GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe(){

    $datos=$this->imagenTemporal;
    $respuesta=controllerOperadorCafes::mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos);
     echo $respuesta;

}
}

public function mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos){


    list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($datos);

    if ($ancho < 1024 || $alto < 768) {

        echo 0;

    }else{

        $datosController=array("ruta"=>$datos,
                                "id"=>$_GET['id']);

        DatosOperadorCafe::subirImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");
        $respuesta=DatosTienda::mostrarImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");

        echo $respuesta['ruta'];

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el JS?

Comment: Y para que deseas ver el JS? en la funcion recibo perfectamente el valor por ajax, mi problema es para obtener el $_GET y pasarlo al controlador

Comment: estas pasando bien el parámetro **GET** digo debería ser algo así `http://myuri.com?id=123456`. En resumen tu codigo parece correcto, la pregunta esta incompleta.

Comment: Si amigo, el problema es que tengo que capturarla desde el archivo ajaxcontroller, para enviarla desde alli al controlador

Comment: ¿Has intentado firmar tu función como `GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe($id)` y llamarla como `$c->GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe($_GET["id"]);`?

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider No te entiendo amigo, podrías explicarme mejor?

Comment: Ya entendi, pero en definitiva no estoy recibiendo la variable $_GET en el archivo ajaxController.php, que puedo hacer?

Comment: Probé tu código y si me funciona, ¿estás seguro que está llegando la variable $_GET?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ayuda para obtener variable $\_GET en una funcion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98120/ayuda-para-obtener-variable-get-en-una-funcion)

Comment: En ningun sitio veo que utilizas `$_GET['id']` dentro de la funcion, o me pierdo de algo?

Comment: en mi pregunta comento que cuando intento capturar $_GET['id'] dentro de la función me dice que esta indefinida, pero si quito el parámetro $datos de la función si me la reconoce

Comment: A ver, ¿tu función es parte de una clase llamada `controllerOperadorCafes`? El mensaje de error parece indicar que no. ¿Puedes mostrar cuál es el constructor de esa clase?

Comment: En esa clase esta esa función, ya actualice el código incluyendo la clase

Comment: ¿Ese código quieres ejecutarlo dentro de la clase o fuera? Tal y como lo tienes, si estás usando un framework, es probable que no te funciona como esperas.

Comment: ¿Qué framework estás usando y cómo defines la ruta? Es probable que no te llegue nunca la "id" si no defines correctamente la ruta y, además, si usas un framework y usas ese código es probable que no haga lo que esperas porque el código está fuera de la función.

Comment: No dupliques preguntas. Si tienes más información que añadir, hazlo en la pregunta original en lugar de crear una pregunta nueva. He combinado las dos preguntas en una sola y movido los datos adicionales a ésta.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro por la aclaratoria, ya volví a actualizar mi pregunta explicando mejor el caso

Answer (score 1):

Ampliando mi comentario, inténtalo de este modo:

```
class AjaxOC {

  public $id;

  public function GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe($id)
  {
    $this->id = $id;   // Esto es opcional
    $datos = $this->imagenTemporal; // Supongo que esto lo tienes definido
    var_dump($id); //
    echo "<br>";
    $respuesta= controllerOperadorCafes::mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos, $id);
    echo $respuesta;
  }

}


if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $c= new AjaxOC();
  $c->GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe($_GET['id']);
}
```

Aunque por la estructura que veo que intentas manejar, deberías incluir un [constructor](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) en tu clase:

```
class AjaxOC {
  public $id;

  public function GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe()
  {
    $datos = $this->imagenTemporal;
    // var_dump($id);
    echo "<br>";
    $respuesta= controllerOperadorCafes::mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos, $id);
    echo $respuesta;
  }

  public __construct($id)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }
}


if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $c= new AjaxOC($_GET['id']);
  $c->GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe();
}
```

Comment: aún nada amigo, yo intento pasar variable desde alli a esta funcion: 

public function mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos,$id){

   $datosController=array("ruta"=>$ruta,
         "id"=>$id);

   DatosOperadorCafe::subirImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");
   $respuesta=DatosTienda::mostrarImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");

   echo $respuesta['ruta'];

  }

 }

porque desde aca tampoco la puedo capturar

Comment: En esa funcion que te copié como ya trae parametros no me deja usar la variable $_GET dentro me la muestra indefinida si la coloco sin parametros, si la puedo usar, porque?

Comment: Lo que ocurra dentro de `AjaxOC` no tiene ninguna relación con lo que suceda en la petición. Al constructor le dará igual si `$id` la defines manualmente o si es el valor de `$_GET[...]`. Todo lo que hagas dentro de la clase será con sus propias variables. Fuera de eso, ¿alguno de los dos códigos te sirvió?

Comment: No me ha servido ningún código, sigo con el mismo problema