# Ayuda para obtener variable $_GET en una función

Tags: php

Intenté capturar la variable directamente dentro de la función y me dice que está indefinida, si quito el parámetro `$datos` sí me reconoce la variable `$id=$_GET["id"]`.

```
class controllerOperadorCafes{
public $id;
public function 
  mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos){
        $id=$this->id;
        $datosController=array("ruta"=>$datos,
                                "id"=>$id);


DatosOperadorCafe::subirImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");
        $respuesta=DatosOperadorCafe::mostrarImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");

        echo $respuesta['ruta'];

    }

  }
}
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $c= new controllerOperadorCafes();
 $c->id=$_GET['id'];
 }
```

Necesito pasar la variable que obtengo por GET en esa función.

Probándola así me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\backend\controllers\controlleropcafe.php on line 
>   193

Y esta es mi línea 193:

```
 $id=$this->id;
```